# Read most recently inserted rows by Date using linq to Entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a log table in my db and wants to fetch only those records which are added most recently based on the column name RowCreateDate, this is how I am trying to achieve the records which is bringing the rows from the db but I feel may be there is a better way to achieve the same.

```
using (var context = new DbEntities())
        {
            // get date
            var latestDate = context.Logs.Max(o => o.RowCreateDate);

            if(latestDate!=null)
            {
                lastDate = new DateTime(latestDate.Value.Year, latestDate.Value.Month, latestDate.Value.Day,00,00,00);

                logs = context.Logs.Where( o.RowCreateDate >= lastDate).ToList();
            }
        }
```

**What i need to know I am doing right or there would another better way?**

Comment: How can any row satisfy `o.RowCreateDate >= lastDate` when `lastDate` is already `Max(RowCreateDate)`?

Comment: @haim770 - It seems that OP changes `lastDate` to the first minute of that day, and thus only compares if the log was created during the last day.

Comment: @smoksnes, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another option:

```
context.Logs.Where(c => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.RowCreateDate) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(context.Logs.Max(o => o.RowCreateDate)))
```

This reads explicitly like what you want (get all rows with date equals max date) and will also result in one query (not two as you might have expected).

Answer (score 0):

You can't simplify this code because LINQ to Entities does not support TakeWhile method.

You can use

```
using (var context = new DbEntities())
{        
    // get date
    var latestDate = context.Logs.Max(o => o.RowCreateDate);

    if(latestDate!=null)
    {
        lastDate = new DateTime(latestDate.Value.Year, latestDate.Value.Month, latestDate.Value.Day,00,00,00);
        logs = context.Logs
            .OrderBy(o => o.RowCreateDate)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .TakeWhile(o => o.RowCreateDate >= lastDate);
    }
}
```

BUT it takes all your data from DB, which is not very good and I do not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do (if we assume you want to get top 3 most recent record):

```
var topDates = context.Logs.OrderByDescending(x=>x.RowCreateDate).Take(3)
```

Comment: why are you saying .Take(3)

Comment: @Shax this will take only 3 records, minimizing the amount of data taken from DB, you can do it without it, if you want all records ordered by `RowCreateDate`

Comment: I don't want all the records, I only want the most recently inserted records by date.

Comment: @Shax, it should have a boundary right. how much records you want? what you mean by most recently records? if I have to show most recent records I will perform order by desc on auto identity column as it will give me most recent data. now its upto you how much recent data you want?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think that your code is fine. I don't see the problem with the two queries. But if you want to simplify it you use [`TruncateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx), like this:

```
    IGrouping<DateTime?, Logs>  log =
        context.Logs.GroupBy(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.RowCreateDate))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

It will return a grouped result with the logs created during the last day for `RowCreateDate`.